# how can I get data in April, because April is in the middle of March and May

Tags: python

`caseMarch_indonesia = case_indonesia[case_indonesia['Date'] < '4/1/20']`
`caseApril_indonesia = case_indonesia[case_indonesia['Date'] >= '4/1/20']`
`caseMay_indonesia = case_indonesia[case_indonesia['Date'] >= '5/1/20']`

how can i get data in April, because April is in the middle of March and May

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to understand what's being asked, but from what i got you need to use

```
caseApril_indonesia = case_indonesia[(case_indonesia['Date'] >= '4/1/20') * (case_indonesia['Date'] < '5/1/20')]
```